# how to get the selected object in a listbox ---wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox

i have three listboxes, whose itemsSource is binded to a list, list and dictionary. i want to add the selected user and selected book to the dictionary with a command but i can't take the selected items. i am trying to obey the mvvm. i have a booklist and a userlist in my viewmodel which are binded to the given listboxes in my view. i couldn't send the selected items to my viewmodel. how can i do this?
thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Why do you say you can't get the selected items in your VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind a property to SelectedItem:

```
<ListBox 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook}"/>
```

And in the ViewModel

```
public class Library : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<Book> Books {get;private set;}
  public Book SelectedBook {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your viewModel, couldn't you create a SelectedBook and a SelectedUser and bind those to the SelectedItem of your ListBoxes?  Then, when they change, add them to your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use standard binding syntax using a slash (/).

```
{Binding Books/}
```

will allow you to bind directly to the current item in a collection.